# Java String not storing same value when assigned to Scanner NextLine()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, system.in

I have come across a problem with the console handler of my code. I don't know if reading `in` after assigning it to `s.nextLine();` discards the current value of `in`. Not sure if anything else could affect the String from being read correctly in one line, and incorrectly in the next.

Thanks in advance!

```
while (loop == true) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = s.nextLine();
        String in = a;
        info("User input: " + in, "DEBUG", 0);
        if (in == "kill") {
            info("Are you sure you would like to kill the running instance? [Y/N]", "CONSOLE", 0);
            if (in == "Y" || in == "y") {
                info("Starting KILL method.", "CONSOLE", 0);
                s.close();
                loop = false
            } else if (in == "N" || in == "n") {
                info("Cancelled.", "CONSOLE", 0);
            } else {
                info("Illegal arguements given. Cancelled.", "CONSOLE", 0);
            }

        } else {
            info("Illegal Arguements given.", "CONSOLE", 0);
        }

    }
```

When I typed `kill` in the console, it gave me this:

```
[info @ DEBUG/0]> User input: kill
[info @ CONSOLE/0]> Illegal Arguements given.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For String compare you should use .equals:

```
while (loop == true) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = s.nextLine();
        String in = a;
        info("User input: " + in, "DEBUG", 0);
        if ("kill".equals(in)) {
            info("Are you sure you would like to kill the running instance? [Y/N]", "CONSOLE", 0);
            if ("Y".equals(in) || "y".equals(in)) {
                info("Starting KILL method.", "CONSOLE", 0);
                s.close();
                loop = false
            } else if ("N".equals(in) || "n".equals(in)) {
                info("Cancelled.", "CONSOLE", 0);
            } else {
                info("Illegal arguments given. Cancelled.", "CONSOLE", 0);
            }

        } else {
            info("Illegal arguments given.", "CONSOLE", 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check equality of strings (and other objects) with `.equals()` method, not with `==` operator.